# What's the expected number of days of the year on which at least 2 people in a group of 10 have the same birthday?

Tags: probability, birthday

This question assumes that a year has 365 days, and each day of the year is equally likely to be a birthday for someone.

At first I thought I simply had to select a day and then 2 individuals ($\frac{\binom{10}{2}}{365}$, but then this can't make sense because I am seeking how many days, not people.

Comment: You have 365 slots and will throw balls randomly and want to know how many slots will be occupied by two balls.

Comment: +1. This is a nice take on the old "birthday paradox", as it's sometimes called.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The probability a given day has no birthdays is  $\left(1-\frac{1}{365}\right)^{10}$ so the expected number of days with no birthday is $365$ times this, about $355.1224$.

The probability a given day has exactly one birthday is  $10 \times \frac{1}{365} \times \left(1-\frac{1}{365}\right)^9$ so the expected number of days with exactly one birthday is $365$ times this, about $9.7561$.

Subtract these two figures from $365$ and you get a result of about $0.1215$ for the expected number of days with two or more birthdays.

Comment: Ah, thanks. Each day independently has a $(\frac{364}{365})^{10}$ probability of having no birthdays... and similar for exactly 1 birthday. Thanks! That makes sense.

Comment: @David: They are not independent, but that does not matter when taking the expectation of a sum